# FabricJS canvas on drag over event fires after drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Have such code :

```js
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  hoverCursor: 'pointer',
  selection: false
});

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  left: 0,
  top: 50,
  angle: 30,
  fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
});
canvas.add(rect1);
$canvas.droppable({
  drop: dragDrop,
  over: enterIn,

});

function enterIn(e, ui) {
  event.preventDefault();
  rect1.width = 400;

}

function dragDrop(e, ui) {

  var element = ui.draggable;

  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(element.data("image"), {
    left: x,
    top: y,

  });
  canvas.add(imgInstance);

}
```

**Problem:**

rect1 width change is applied only after drop on canvas.
But I tested that **enterIn** function is working fine.

Could you advise something?

Comment: Fix it! I must refresh canvas -    rect1.setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll(); inside enterIn().